# UIActivityViewController not working after iOS 16 update

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have the following code in my Xamarin.iOS project:

```
public void sendEmail(NSData pdfData)
{
    sharedItems[0] = pdfData;

    var activityController = new UIActivityViewController(sharedItems, null);
    activityController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = this.View;
    activityController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceRect = new CoreGrapCGRect(View.Frame.Width/2 + 240, View.Frame.Width / 2 - 160, 0, 0);
    activityController.PopoverPresentationController.PermittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Down;

    PresentViewController(activityController, true, null);
}
```

It was working before on iOS 15 and 16. Today I updated my device to iOS 16.3.1 and now when the popup opens, it's completely blank.

Note: I could not send the pdf file in the Outlook app before my update (on iOS 16), but it at least wasn't a blank pop up.

Comment: What kind of device did you test it on? The iPhone or the iPad? When I tested it on the iPhone, the null exception will be thrown.

Comment: When I test on iOS16.2 simulator, it works. But when I run the same code on my physical iPad with iOS 16.3.1, the popup is completely blank. I don't know why null exception is thrown for you.

Comment: I tested it on iPhone simulator, and you are right, it crashes with null exception because `PopoverPresentationController` is null. But it is not null when I run the same code on iPad. If I remove reference to `PopoverPresentationController` it will work on iPhone, but crash on iPad.

Comment: I would manually delete app from device, power off/restart the phone again, Download app again. Shouldn't be needed with a production release from app store, but app building/testing during app development has dependencies that might be affected by OS upgrade. Its even possible that you'll need an update to xcode and visual studio before development builds install correctly on latest OS. Sometimes Microsoft doesn't resolve all issues until days later. Its an ongoing task for Microsoft / Visual Studio to catch up with Apple's changes. I'm just guessing might be the case here.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve that worked and everything is working now. Thanks!